# 401 Unauthorized error while making Paypal Credit Card Payment

Tags: oauth-2.0, paypal

I want a user to accept payment from credit card using paypal. so I have authorized the user from a application and making call as mentioned in this link
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/

and here is a curl request I am making form my local Machine

```
  curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment \

  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  -H "Authorization:Bearer 22SKUmLAeeKccfG-FmJdFiT97FLQnjSbeDHDN0hHdEQ" \
  -d '{
        "intent":"sale",
        "payer":{
        "payment_method":"credit_card",
        "funding_instruments":[
         {
           "credit_card":{
             "number":"4417119669820331",
             "type":"visa",
             "expire_month":11,
             "expire_year":2018,
             "cvv2":"874",
             "first_name":"Joe",
             "last_name":"Shopper",
      "billing_address":{
        "line1":"52 N Main ST",
        "city":"Johnstown",
        "country_code":"US",
        "postal_code":"43210",
        "state":"OH"
      }
    }
  }
]
},
"transactions":[
{
  "amount":{

"total":"7.47",
    "currency":"USD",
    "details":{
      "subtotal":"7.41",
      "tax":"0.03",
      "shipping":"0.03"
    }
  },
  "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
  }
]
}'
```

And I get a following error "401 Unauthorized"

Can anyone help me what I am missing in above call. or any additional scope is required for making credit card payments.

Answer (score 1):

Try getting a new access token and using it as part of your call:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/#get-an-access-token

A 401 generally means that you don't have the right access token or it has expired.